# making the first letter of each word color css

Tags: html, css

I've a logo text in anchor tag and the Text logo to have the first letter of ever word red.

```
<a href="http://frobbeintl.com" title="">FLETCHER ROBBE INTERNATIONAL LLP</a>
```

Like below image:

[image]

I've used span but it doesn't seem working in my scenario. Can some one point me to some CSS approach? Thanks

Comment: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoelement-firstletter

Comment: How do you distinguish between a word (Flecther) and an acronym (LLP)?

Comment: @Sean Bright: There is no such way to distinguish between these letters

Comment: What have you actually tried?

Answer (score 2):

[**Working JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/YQ4qL/1/)

This is the best you can do for inline elements in pure HTML + CSS:

```
<a class = "name" href="http://frobbeintl.com" title="">
  <span>F</span>letcher
  <span>R</span>obbe
  <span>I</span>nternational
  <span>LLP</span<
</a>
```

CSS:

```
.name {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  }

.name span {
  color: red;
  }
```

<strike>You could use the `::first-letter` selector, as in [CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/f/first-letter/).</strike> <- only for block elements

Answer (score 1):

Although you can use this property

```
a::first-letter {
   color: red;
}
```

But note this would be applied to the very first word in the Hyperlink, not in the word.

Here is a document for this http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/f/first-letter/

Comment: Applied to the very first letter you mean.

Comment: Yes, it would be only applied to the very first letter inside the element, Not to the every first letter in the word in the hyperlink. You can again use the spans!

Comment: `The pseudo element only works if the parent element is a block container box (in other words, it doesn't work on the first letter of display: inline; elements.)`

Answer (score 0):

You could change your code to the following:

```
<a href="http://frobbeintl.com" title=""><span>F</span>LETCHER <span>R</span>OBBE <span>I</span>NTERNATIONAL <span>LLP</span></a>
```

Having that you can style the spans differently. From a markup standpoint that's fine because span has no meaning.
Using this technique and ids/nth-child you can even go as far as styling every letter differently.
As you see this gets ugly very quickly - so someone created a little jQuery plugin to do it for you: http://letteringjs.com/

Hope that helps.